# compiz scale plugin arrow movement breaks sometimes

Tags: ubuntu, compiz

The arrow keys cycles between the windows. But sometimes it won't let me switch to window down, just left or right and other times it won't let me go up. I'm not sure if this is a feature or a bug, more likely the latter.

Comment: Probably belongs over @ askubuntu.com.

Comment: @boehj Compiz isn't specific to Ubuntu, so it should be fine here

Comment: Asking for some update: did software upgrades solved the issue or not?

Comment: I don't know, I moved to mac late last year.